# Is it safe to use cipher block sizing instead of padding?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, cbc, padding

I'm using this kind of technique instead of padding of cipher buffer (here goes pseudo-code):

```
struct {
   int size;         //size of cipher buffer
   byte[32] vector; //random IV (block size is 256 bits)
   byte[] buffer;    //encrypted buffer
}
```

Cipher data encrypted using block cipher with CBC chaining using IV specified as `vector`

I'm storing this structure "as-is" and in order to decrypt it decrypting buffer block by block then just cutting buffer to `size`.

Question is: is it safe/secure? Any hints/criticizm?

Comment: that sounds like a memory access problem waiting to happen

Comment: So you are zero padding to block length and storing the actual length in plain text? One consideration is that you need to authenticate the length or else an attacker can add some zeros to the end or lop some more bytes out.

Comment: Add or lop bytes to cipher data? And what's danger of that?

Comment: @barmaley, what is the danger of being able to modify the message? That depends on what you are using the encryption for.

Comment: In my case it's not a problem. And anyway attacker can change cipher message - doesn't matter is it padded or not

Comment: @barmaley, yes, that is why authentication is almost always a good idea, I merely pointed out that you'd need to include the size as part of authenticated data.

Comment: do you mean calculating of hash of size+vector+message?

Comment: @barmaley, a MAC rather than a hash, but essentially.

Comment: 256-bit **block** size, really? What cipher is this?

Comment: it's Rijndael cipher

Comment: Rijndael cipher (AES) block size is 128 bits unless you are using some special implementation ?? *Key size* is 128 / 192 or *256 bits*.

Comment: Rijndael supports several block size, AES is Rijndael with a block size of 128-bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.

There is a practical disadvantage in space used, if you don't otherwise need to store the size in plaintext. A size field will usually take 32 or 64 bits, whereas typical padding adds one byte on average. Also, if you use [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) you need to include the length as part of the authenticated data.

Comment: Of course, the deciphering party should validate the `size` field: sign, maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally fine EXCEPT the fact, that you should not think that one replaces another : it's the BEST practice to use both, but using one of them is better than not using anything at all. They're helping each other in terms of securing, and they are different things.

Comment: Too weird to understand your point, dude ))

Comment: @barmaley The point IS that padding increases the security just by being applied, because no "zerofill trail" and another weak conditions are present in the system. Regardless of the "key length"/"block size"/"bits elaborated". And the increase of  "key length"/"block size"/"bits elaborated" is increasing the cost of cracking system(=makes the system more secure), even without any padding at all. They are complementary, they are not replacing each other and not a competing techniques. That's my point.

Comment: Not really sure that padding increases security, in some cases it's vulnerability. See [padding oracle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack)

Comment: @barmaley There are many types of padding and no strict standart for it : it's just a type of process. Design your own schema and embed into your system.

Comment: I don't see any advantage from using both. Padding [does not](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/29999/49923) add security. Also, there definitely are standards for padding, like in PKCS#5.

Comment: @otus of course there are some variants of padding standardized! But there's no strict requirement of using only standardized padding. And about adding a security - some standardized padding types may not add one, but not all of them